# barplot multiple aggregation

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataframe "count" that look like this:

```
#                 Date      Code   Number_of_events
#1                  01-04  022003        5
#2                  01-06  022003        9
#3                  01-08  022003        3
#4                  01-11  022003        2
#5                  01-13  022003        5
#...
#3754               03-11  396001        4
#3755               03-16  396001        4
#3756               03-21  396001       17
#3757               03-22  396001       23
#3758               03-23  396001        3
```

That I got as result of aggregate a df by Date and Code:

```
count<-aggregate(.~ Date+Code,data=df,FUN=sum)
```

I want to do a barplot of the number of events (y) versus the date (x) in wich each code is a series (hence a colored bar). Knowing that the events don't happend in the exact same dates.

Could anybody help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ggplot2` package, which contains a convenient `geom_bar()` function.

Simulate some data:

```
# simulate some data
N <- 100
df <- data.frame(Date = sample(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 48), N, T),
                    Code = sample(c(022003, 396001, 441002), size = N, replace = T),
                    Number_of_events = rpois(N, 5))

#aggregate
count <- aggregate(.~ Date+Code,data=df,FUN=sum)
```

This is for the plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(count, aes(x=Date, y=Number_of_events)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=as.factor(Code)), color="black", stat="identity", position="stack")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `barplot`

```
barplot(xtabs(Number_of_events~Code + Date, df), 
               beside = TRUE, legend = TRUE, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

---

Or using `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
     group_by(Date, Code) %>%
     summarise(Number_of_events = sum(Number_of_events)) %>%
     ggplot(., aes(x= Date, y = Number_of_events)) + 
       geom_bar(aes(fill= factor(Code)), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```